# Detect SKPhysicsBody collision after SKPhysicsBody has been applied

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, game-physics, skphysicsbody

I have simple gameplay that functions like this:

[image]

My goal is to detect when the ball hits the white part (game over scene would load) or when the ball hits the gray part (game continues)

Because the shapes shrink and have a lot of stuff going on, I figured it would be a lot more efficient to just create the SKPhysicsBody when I need it, and then remove it after the collision checks happen. So when I click the screen this happens: (after 5*0.0325 seconds--how long it takes the circle to shrink--has passed, it will add the physicsbody to both the gray and white part so I can detect which the ball is touching)

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + seconds, execute: {
        let trackPhysics = SKPhysicsBody(texture: track.texture!, size: track.texture!.size())
        trackPhysics.isDynamic = false
        trackPhysics.affectedByGravity = false
        track.physicsBody = trackPhysics

        let goalPhysics = SKPhysicsBody(texture: goal.texture!, size: goal.texture!.size())
        goalPhysics.isDynamic = false
        goalPhysics.affectedByGravity = false
        goal.physicsBody = goalPhysics
    })
```

Which works. The SKPhysicsBody are applied to both the gray and white part perfectly without any loss in framerate and follow the rotation. The problem is... how do I detect which is the ball touching? Since they did not formally collide, it will not call the collision at all (which makes sense since they did not really collide

This is the basic logic, and it works perfectly until I want to check the results:

1. someone touches the screen
2. circles shrink
3. right after they shrink it will create an SKPhysicsBody for both the gray and white part based on its texture
4. Problem is here... how do I detect which the ball is touching?

I have tried this:

```
    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        print("touching!")
    }

    func didEnd(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        print("not touching")
    }
```

which has no messages at all, and have tried using allContactedBodies() 1 second after the SKPhysicsBody were applied, but returns a count with 0 for all of them. I have even tried making this 5 seconds and still not working

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + seconds + 1, execute: {
        print(track.physicsBody!.allContactedBodies().count)
        print(goal.physicsBody!.allContactedBodies().count)
    })
```

This is what it looks like with the SKPhysicsBody applied, you can see the physics is applied perfectly

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try setting the physics body's `isDynamic` property to `true`? Physics bodies need to be dynamic for collision detection to work.

Comment: Ok that made it so physicsBody!.allContactedBodies().count returns 10 so now it notices they are touching, but the collision delgate still says nothing and the screen is all messed up, http://i.imgur.com/b9UxA8r.jpg. How would I get it from not messing up like that?

Comment: Are you setting the `physicsWorld.contactDelegate`? That needs to be set for the `didBeginContact` method to fire.

Comment: I fixed the screen messing up by setting the world speed to 0, `self.physicsWorld.speed = 0` I also set the world's contact delegate to itself in the didMove `self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self`. It still does not display anything inside of the didBegin(contact:) or didEnd(contact:) functions though. Maybe I can get away with using `allContactedBodies()` unless you have any other ideas? Thanks a lot for your help so far!!

Comment: You should figure out why `didBegin(contact:)` is not being called. Once this is working, you can use it to determine which nodes the ball is touching (your original question).

Comment: @nathan I was actually able to figure it out! I had the masks pointing to the wrong numbers so it did not pick up the collision. Thanks a lot for the help!!

Comment: No problem. I posted a brief summary answer below in case anyone else comes across a similar issue in the future. Good luck with your game!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution (as discovered in the comments above), was:

1. Set the `isDynamic` property of nodes to `true` for collision detection to work properly.
2. Ensure that `didBegin(contact:)` is being called, by double-checking that the scene's `physicsWorld.contactDelegate` is set.
3. Ensure the masks and physics bodies are set at the proper times and locations.